# Firebase Cloud Messaging without google credentials

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an android app and I want to insert a chat into it.
I read I could use FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging) to develop the chat, but I want to know one thing: is it possible to use FCM without logging in with google credentials on my app?

Comment: FCM and Firebase Auth are separate projects. Why do you think you need to login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase realtime db can be used to create chat apps in tandem with usage of Firebase cloud messaging. However if you want to keep the DB safe and secured, you will need some form of Authentication.

This does not necessarily have to be google auth. Check out Firebase Auth and the methods they support.

Alternatively, you can use Google oauth apis to generate an Auth token and use them with Firebase REST apis and not have to use Firebase auth.

Summary: Yes you can build the chat app with Firebase RTDB and FCM without google auth or any auth. But it's advisable to use some for of Auth (Firebase auth, Google oauth, Twitter oauth or Facebook oauth are such examples)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use Firebase Cloud Messaging without requiring the users of your app to sign in. Each app instance is identified by a so-called FCM token. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client