# Do I need to use firebase authentication, to use messenger?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

All of the documentation assumes we are already intending to use fire-base authentication. We already have a working authentication system. All we want is support for push notifications. Can I use firebase cloud messenger without having client devices authentication pass through firebase?

Comment: In addition to Doug's excellent answer, also see Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43836240 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/44187809

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Messaging has no dependencies on Firebase Authentication.  They share no infrastructure.  If the documentation is ever confusing on this point, please find the that was misleading and use the "send feedback" button at the top of that page to explain what was misleading.

FCM doesn't require the use of any authentication libraries.  You can use it standlone.  FCM uses a token assigned to a device in order to message that device.  It doesn't target users (who might be using multiple devices).  It only targets individual devices (and topics for subscription).  If you want to map a device token to a registered with another auth system, you're free to do that.